# Using ofstream to write text to the end of a file

Tags: c++, ofstream

How do I use the ofstream to write text to the end of a file without erasing its content inside?

Answer (score 7):

You can pass the flag `ios::app` when opening the file:

```
ofstream ofs("filename", ios::app);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to append to the file. Use ios::app as the file mode when creating the ofstream.

Appending will automatically seek to the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

As people have mentioned above, opening the file in the following manner will do:

`ofstream out("path_to_file",ios::app);`

It will do the trick, if you want to append data to the file by default.

But, if you want to go to the end of the file, in the middle of the program, with the default mode not being `ios::app`, you can use the following statement:

`out.seekp(0,ios::end)`
This will place the put pointer 0 bytes from the end of file. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp

Make sure you use the correct seekp(), as there are 2 overloads of seekp(). The one with 2 parameters is favored in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use ios::app as the file mode.

Answer (score 0):

The `seekp()` function allows you to arbitrarily set the position of the file pointer, for open files.